# Как сохранить html страницу без знаков вопроса?

Tags: python, html

```
import requests

url = "https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/backgrounds/231926.html"

r = requests.get(url)
with open('file.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

Если открывать такой такой сайт после сохранения появляются знаки вопроса вместо текста или картинок.

Comment: Вообще ничего не появляется, даже знаки вопроса. `Access denied Error code 1020`. В браузере то же самое. Если это сайт под логином и паролем, вряд ли SO сможет помочь.

Comment: open('file.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Linux Ваш код сработает правильно. Скорее всего Вы выполняете его в Windows. А это значит, что файл создается в кодировке Windows-1251. А в html разметке в head указано, что файл браузер должен читать как utf-8. Необходимо немного изменить код:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.templatemonster.com/ru/backgrounds/231926.html"

r = requests.get(url)
with open('file.html', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Так и есть.На линукс все работало нормально, а на виндовс нет.Спасибо.